# Limit memory and execution of dynamic script in Java

Tags: java, scripting

I have an idea for a game. The core mechanic is based on entering a script that controls your character, somewhat like Screeps. This makes multiplayer very easy to implement, as you only need to sync the initial world state and then everybody watches their characters run off.

I have two problems in going about this.

I want to ensure that every character gets a fair slice of time, regardless of how loaded the server is. It won't do to say each character gets X ms of execution time because the amount of work done in that time may vary based how loaded the client is and its hardware. I want, regardless of if I run the code on a Raspberry Pi or a top of the line i7, to execute the same amount of code.

I also want to ensure that, if playing with untrusted players, the submitted code from other clients can't consume excessive memory or access any resources it shouldn't be allowed to.

What's the best course of action to accomplish this?

An easy approach would be to have players program according to some assembly standard I invent, then letting each character run X ops for game-tick. But I fear that'll reduce the accessibility, so I'd rather use a scripting language like Lua, JavaScript, or Python.